# How to determine if SQL Server version is Web Edition - Expecting Web but seeing Standard

Tags: sql-server, version

As per the title, I'm trying tpo find the version of SQL server, which I have done several ways already, and each time I'm only seeing Standard edition. The reason for my question is that I'm expecting to see web edition, and I've not seen any reference on the web about web edition versions.

```
Your current Microsoft SQL Server information:
Product Version:          12.0.2000.8
Product Name:             SQL Server 2014
Product Level:            RTM 
Product Edition:          Standard Edition (64-bit)
```

If it is indeed Standard then that's great as it's what I need, but i'd like to be able to rule out that it's not web edition. Thanks.

Comment: Which "several ways" have you tried? `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')` should give you the edition. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms174396.aspx

Comment: Indeed I had tried that one but the page is a good reference and confirms that the version is Standard. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to determine the edition, perhaps the easiest is

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')
```

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321185 for a more complete discussion.